# Error creating multiple map annotations from a parse class

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I'm trying to create annotations from Parse backend but I get an error  `'[PFObject]?' is not convertible to '[PFObject]'`

I based my code on a question i found here [Query a GeoPoint from Parse and add it to MapKit as MKAnnotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29807428/query-a-geopoint-from-parse-and-add-it-to-mapkit-as-mkannotation)

Heres a pic of my code and the error. [code photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIXvc.png)

```
{

mapView.showsUserLocation = true
mapView.delegate = self
mapView.setUserTrackingMode(MKUserTrackingMode.Follow, animated: true)
MapViewLocationManager.delegate = self
MapViewLocationManager.startUpdatingLocation()


    var annotationQuery = PFQuery(className: "Movers")
     currentLoc = PFGeoPoint(location: MapViewLocationManager.location)
    annotationQuery.whereKey("ubicacion", nearGeoPoint: currentLoc, withinKilometers: 10)
    annotationQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (movers, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            print("Successful query for annotations")

            let myMovers = movers as [PFObject]

                for mover in myMovers {
                let point = movers["ubicacion"] as PFGeoPoint
                let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(point.latitude, point.longitude)
                self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

        }

        }else {
            // Log details of the failure
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please paste your code directly into the question rather than as an image, as it makes answering more difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myMovers` is a `[PFObject]?`, an optional array of `PFObject`s (as in maybe an array of `PFObject`s or maybe `nil`). Because it is an optional, it's not directly convertible to the non optional because you can't convert `nil` to `[PFObject]`. So what you really want is to do a conditional cast here using `as?` and put it in an `if let` statement. Like so

```
if let myMovers = movers as? [PFObject] {
    // Use myMovers to do what you want 
}
```

That will execute what is in the braces only when `movers` is a `[PFObject]` and not `nil`.